# Icon doesn't update when a messagebox is shown at Form1.Load

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Form1.Load, I have:

```
MessageBox.Show("Text blah blah blah");
```

Until you press OK, this is the icon in the Taskbar:

[image: pcture1]

When you press OK, it changes to the icon:

[image: picture2]

**How do I make it update when it starts?**

I changed the icon by changing it in the form properties:

[image: picture3]

Entire "Load" function:

```
string word = "1.4";

var url = "http://chipperyman573.com/rtf/textbot.html";
var client = new WebClient();
using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string downloadedString;
    while ((downloadedString = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (downloadedString == word)
        {
            update = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Congrats! You are running the latest version (" + word + ") of Chip Bot!\n\nGot an idea for this program? Use the \"Send feedback\" button to let me know!", "Chip Bot", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Text = "Chip Bot" + word + " - Got an idea for this program? Send me some feedback!";
        }
        else
        {
            Text = "Chip Bot (UPDATE AVAILABLE)";
            go.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            setup.Enabled = false;
            otherGroup.Enabled = false;
            optionsGroup.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("There is an update! Downloading now! \n\nUNTIL YOU UPDATE THE PROGRAM WILL NOT FUNCTION.", "Chip Bot", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            url = "";
            var web = new WebBrowser();
            web.Navigate(url);
        }
    }
}
```

It does it regardless of if there is an update (`downloadstring != word`) or if there isn't one (`downloadstring == word`)

Comment: Can you show the entire `Load` function code please?

Comment: @DanBarzilay I added it to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`Shown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx) event instead, and I fixed your code with the wrong use of the `WebClient` (I used [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync.aspx)):

```
private void Form1_Shown(Object s1, EventArgs e1) {
    string word = "1.4";

    var url = "http://chipperyman573.com/rtf/textbot.html";
    var client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s2, e2) => 
    {
       if(e2.Error != null)
       {
            //Maybe do some error handling?
       }
       else
       {
            if (e2.Result == word)
            {
                update = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Congrats! You are running the latest version (" + word + ") of Chip Bot!\n\nGot an idea for this program? Use the \"Send feedback\" button to let me know!", "Chip Bot", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Text = "Chip Bot" + word + " - Got an idea for this program? Send me some feedback!";
            }
            else
            {
                Text = "Chip Bot (UPDATE AVAILABLE)";
                go.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                setup.Enabled = false;
                otherGroup.Enabled = false;
                optionsGroup.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("There is an update! Downloading now! \n\nUNTIL YOU UPDATE THE PROGRAM WILL NOT FUNCTION.", "Chip Bot", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                url = "";
                var web = new WebBrowser();
                web.Navigate(url);
            }
       }
    };

    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute)); 
}
```

Comment: Remember to register the `Shown` event to this func. (like you did to the `Load` event)

Comment: I think you only fixed one: http://puu.sh/3hj5Y.png ... I searched google and couldn't find out how to fix this.

Comment: @TheFlubbs I fixed it again.. (another stupid mistake, `e` instead of `e2`)